# javascript - ajax - jsf - bean interaction

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a `selectBooleanCheckbox` (CB) and two `inputText`s (IT1, IT2) all bounded to the resp. bean fields.

When CB is selected I want that the value of IT1 and IT2 are set to default values and disabled, while when the CB is deselected, IT1 and IT2 have to be enabled and emptied.

At the moment I tried this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[ 
    function myFunction()
    {
      if(document.getElementById("detailForm:CB").checked)
      {
        document.getElementById("detailForm:IT2").value = "";
        document.getElementById("detailForm:IT1").value = "00:01";
      }
    }
  //]]>
</script>
```

and

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox
   id="CB"
   value="#{detailModel.afterObject.defaultDefinition}"
   onclick="myFunction()"
   disabled="#{detailModel.mode == detailModel.viewMode or !loggedUser.isAdmin()}">
     <f:ajax render="IT1 IT2 @this" execute="@this"/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

and

```
<h:inputText
  id="IT1"
  value="#{bean.IT1}"
  disabled="#{detailModel.mode == detailModel.viewMode or bean.CB}" />
```

and

```
<rich:calendar
  id="IT2"
  value="#{(bean.CB== false) ? detailModel.IT2 : ''}"
  datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd"
  enableManualInput="true"
  disabled="#{detailModel.mode == detailModel.viewMode or bean.CB}"/>
</rich:calendar>
```

All it's ok if I create a new object/bean.

The problem is when I want to edit an existing object/bean: with the `f:ajax render="IT1 IT2 @this" execute="@this"` the page is reloaded and the old values overwrite the values set by the javascript function...

The value of IT2 is not directly bounded to the bean (`value="#{(bean.CB== false) ? detailModel.IT2 : ''}"`). This because it has to be modified before showing it.

I hope you understand my description of the problem and could help me solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ActionListener** for checkbox and reset the bounded check box values in your listener method (better to place this method in your existing action bean class) and also use **render** attribute to fetch the current values of those input fields.